# how to write SQL - WHERE column LIKE 'something%' in python?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm searching an SQL table for customers who's name starts with my input and i have problem writing the "Starting With" logic, it works fine when its WHERE ? =.
i'm using pyodbc and using driver ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

i've seen alot of answers on similar problems but they always refer to using the code %s, and that does not work when i try it

I've tried many different ways of writing LIKE '%' but i cannot find any examples of this

my current code is:

```
  cursor.execute("select CustomerName, CustomerNum From customer WHERE Company = ? AND CustomerName = ?", Company, CustomerName)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in result:
      print (row)
```

CustomerName var set to "Mic" and the the result should be:

Microsoft

Micro systems

etc..

Thanks you

Comment: which database are you pulling data from? CONCAT might not be available, you might have to do a '%'+searchstring+%'

Comment: Hi, Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to concatenate the parameter with the `%` wildcard. In MySQL you use the `CONCAT()` function, in SQL-Server you use the `+` operator.

Also, the parameters that fill in the placeholders should be in a tuple, not separate arguments to `cursor.execute()`.

MySQL:

```
  cursor.execute("select CustomerName, CustomerNum From customer WHERE Company = ? AND CustomerName LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')", (Company, CustomerName))
```

SQL-Server:

```
  cursor.execute("select CustomerName, CustomerNum From customer WHERE Company = ? AND CustomerName ? + '%'", (Company, CustomerName))
```